# How to display two group concat'ed columns together in a single column seperated by a customed seperator

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

The follow is the controller function to display the table

```
$rec = DB::table('recipe_list')
    ->select('recipe_list.recipe_id', 'recipe_list.Recipe_name',
        'recipe_list.Recipe_desc', 'recipe_list.Recipe_duration',
        DB::raw('group_concat(distinct ing_list.Ing_name separator ",") as recipe_ingredients'),
        DB::raw('group_concat(distinct recipe_inglist.quantity  separator ",") as ingredients_amount'),
        'recipe_cusine.Cusine_name', 'recipe_type.Recipe_type_name', 'recipe_list.image',
        DB::raw(' count(distinct likerecipes.id) as likes'))
    ->join('recipe_inglist', 'recipe_list.recipe_id', '=', 'recipe_inglist.Recipe_id')
    ->join('ing_list', 'recipe_inglist.Ing_id', '=', 'ing_list.ing_id')
    ->join('recipe_cusine', 'recipe_list.Recipe_cusine_id', '=', 'recipe_cusine.cusine_id')
    ->join('recipe_type', 'recipe_list.Recipe_type_id', '=', 'recipe_type.Recipe_typeID')
    ->join('likerecipes', 'recipe_list.recipe_id', '=', 'likerecipes.recipe_id')
    ->where('recipe_list.recipe_id', '>=', '1')
    ->groupBy('recipe_list.recipe_id', 'recipe_list.recipe_name', 'recipe_list.recipe_desc', 'recipe_list.recipe_duration', 'recipe_cusine.Cusine_name', 'recipe_type.Recipe_type_name', 'recipe_list.image')->get();
```

the table output is
[Recipes Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0PQF.png)

But what I want the output to be is like :

```
|Recipe_id|Name|Description|Cusine|Type |Ingredient        |
|   1     |blah|blahblahbla| bla  | bla | 20 gm of garlic,
                                        | 500 gm of chicken,
                                        | 30 gm of onion,
```

This is my recipe_inglist table
[recipe_inglist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8nGW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to go with php code,

Like this way,

You have `$rec` data, then do below code,

```
foreach ($rec as $k => &$v) {
    $names  = explode(",", $v->recipe_ingredients);
    $amount = explode(",", $v->ingredients_amount);
    $temp   = [];
    foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
        $temp[] = $amount[$key] . ' of ' . $value;
    }
    if ($temp) {
        $v->ingredient = implode(",", $temp);
    }

}
```

Where I am creating `ingradient` field which will have e.g.  `20 gm of garlic,500 gm of chicken,30 gm of onion` as value.

Comment: i kind of get the idea about what you're trying to do, but i dint understand where or how to use this code. I am really new to laravel.

Comment: You are getting $rec records from query, just below that. write above code, and once dd records to cross check

Comment: i was able to get the value of temp by using vardump. and the output was "array(3) { [0]=> string(17) "500 gm of chicken" [1]=> string(14) "30 gm of onion" [2]=> string(15) "20 gm of Garlic" }" so its working. but i dint quite get the idea of how i can display it on the table along with the recipe name and all.

Comment: You can show that field value as $value->ingradient and $value will be your iterarator

Comment: the part that i dint understand is that after i had stored values to $rec i sent it to my recipe.blade.php using "return view('recipe', ['recipe'=>$rec]); " from where i have used @foreach($recipe as $rec) then displayed the data in the column by {{$recipe->recipe_name}} and so on. so what should i do in order to view the data from that $ value in my view in order with the recipe id, name,cusine,....,..,..,ingredient&amount

Comment: here it is $recipe->ingredient